# How to read friend's messages with FB app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-permissions

I'm a new FB developer. I'm trying to create a new FB app, which (when you are logged in) shows you the last wall messages of your friends.
So I tried to ask the "user_posts" permission to facebook for my app, but the answer was:

"This permission cannot be approved because the user_posts permission only gives access to the user's posts, not their friends'".

Do you know how can I make it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You simply can’t.

As https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/feed#read clearly says,

> Your app needs `user_posts` permission from the person who created the post or the person tagged in the post. Then your app can read:
>
> - Timeline posts from the person who gave you the permission.
> - The posts that other people made on that person Timeline.
> - The posts that other people have tagged that person in.

That’s it. Everything else is not available to your app.

Comment: Thanks CBroe for your answer.
I want to read timeline posts of my friends, is not user_posts the correct permission that I ask to facebook?
So, what is the correct permission to ask?

Comment: That is simply not possible. You wanna read stuff from user X, then you need to get permission _from_ user X first.

Comment: Yes, that makes no difference.